# Array to database

Tags: php, database, forms, foreach

how can i insert this to my database?
I tried a lot of ways to do this, but not succesfull.
Also how can i count the amount of input types?

Thank you

```
                           <input class="beschrijving" style="width: 436px" type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
              <input style="width: 60px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" />
              <input style="width: 100px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" />
              <br />
              <br />
              <input class="beschrijving" style="width: 436px" type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
              <input style="width: 60px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" />
              <input style="width: 100px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" />
              <br />
              <br />
              <input class="beschrijving" style="width: 436px" type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
              <input style="width: 60px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" />
              <input style="width: 100px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" />
              <br />
              <br />
              <input class="beschrijving" style="width: 436px" type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
              <input style="width: 60px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" />
              <input style="width: 100px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" />
              <br />
              <br />
              <input class="beschrijving" style="width: 436px" type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
              <input style="width: 60px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" />
              <input style="width: 100px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" />
              <br />
              <br />
              <input class="beschrijving" style="width: 436px" type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
              <input style="width: 60px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" />
              <input style="width: 100px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" />
              <br />
              <br />
          </div>
```

EDIT:

It seems some people don't know what i mean, first of all i'm working with PHP
This is my problem, 
There are multiply input fields in my form with the same name, i have made a array from the names and now i want the values of the array into my database

It tried this but it isn't working,

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ ){
$nummer = $_POST['factuurnaam'];
$des = $_POST['beschrijving[]'.$i];
$amount = $_POST['aantal[]'.$i];
$prijs = $_POST['prijs[]'.$i];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `facturen`(`beschrijving`,`aantal`, `prijs`,      `factuurnaam`) VALUES ('".$des."','".$amount."','".$prijs."','".$nummer."')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to insert this HTML into the database? Do you mean the values of the input fields? Also what programming language? C#, Java, PHP?

Comment: @DarrenDavies Yes i want to insert the values of the input fields in my database, and i'm using php

Comment: what are you looking for here ? what are you using ? .Net ? JavaScript ? Most importantly - **what have you tried so far** ?

Comment: I'd be tempted to add a PHP tag to your question. I think this is quite easy in PHP if I remember correctly - $beschrijving will exist as an array on a page refresh if it's on a form - then a foreach can loop each entry into a database. You can count within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `array_shift` function to get value from all parameter, further for your information in php `$variables` work fine inside double quotes! see the modified code.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $nummer = $_POST['factuurnaam'];  // NOTE: variable not mentioned in HTML form ?
  $des    = array_shift($_POST['beschrijving']);
  $amount = array_shift($_POST['aantal']);
  $prijs  = array_shift($_POST['prijs']);

  $sql    = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `facturen` (`beschrijving`,`aantal`, `prijs`, `factuurnaam`) 
                         VALUES ('$des','$amount','$prijs','$nummer')"
            ) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the input fields:

```
$texttofind = "<input";
echo 'Number of inputfields: ' . substr_count($input, $texttofind);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Insert html into the database is as easy as adding any string to the database, only you have to escape it like this:

```
$html = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

$input has to be your html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what what you will need,

```
$beschrijving = $_POST['beschrijving'];
$aantal       = $_POST['aantal'];
$prijs        = $_POST['prijs'];
```

as all are in the same number, so we can loop any of them

```
for($i=0;$i<count($beschrijving );$i++){
      $sql    = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `facturen` (`beschrijving`,`aantal`, `prijs`) VALUES ('$beschrijving[$i] ','$aantal[$i] ','$prijs[$i] ')"
        )
}
```

I hope this will help you.